# How to access variables in ng-repeat scope in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am populating html drop down list from database with angularjs and I want to access selected value and pass it further to another function to get some more data from database but I cannot access values that is select tag populated with ng-repeat.

```
<select name="boja" ng-model="boja" class="form-control" ng-click="loadState(data.model)">  
<option value="">Odaberi boju</option>  
<option ng-repeat="boja in boje" value="{{boja.boja}}">{{boja.boja}}</option>  </select>



$scope.loadState = function(model){
        $http({
            method:"POST",
            url:"ubaciBoje.php",
            data:{'model':model}
        }).success(function(data){
            $scope.boje = data;
        }); 
};
```

Now when I want to access $scope.boja in another function it says it is undefined. But I am able to access $scope.boje which gives me an array of values. My question is how do i get access to value selected by user and pass it to another function?

Comment: I think you have to pass this in click event ng-click="loadState(boja)"

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
<option ng-repeat="boja in boje" value="{{boja.boja}}">{{boja.boja}}</option>  </select>
```

`boja` will exist here in the view template, and only here. IF you want to use in component code you have to directly pass it from a view as a paramenter eg

```
<option ng-repeat="boja in boje" value="{{boja.boja}}">{{someComponentMethod(boja.boja)}}</option>
```

and since `boje` isa scope (here component) field, you can access it whenever you want.

Comment: I want to access $scope.boja in another function when user selects value from drop down list. $scope.boja will be selected value.

Comment: You would have to pass it from view as method argument like i wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

Here `ng-click` in `select` statement is not a good choice. `angularjs` has a very good directive for selecting and generating `select` html template.

```
<select ng-options="boja as boja.boja for boja in boje" ng-model="selectedBoja" ng-change="loadState(selectedBoja)"></select>
```

Here `selectedBoja` is you selected item when user change item drom select.